# How to create Azure function App in Python without using Visual Code Studio

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I want to create an Azure Function App using python language. But I don't want to use any tools like Visual Code Editor. I want to use the inline code editor of azure because my code is not that big.

I created a function app with below details:

```
publish: code
stack: python
version: 3.7
Region: Central US
OS: Linux
Plan Type: Consumption
```

But after the function app is created it did not allow me to use inline editor. I get the below error

```
Editing functions in the Azure portal is not supported for Linux Consumption Function Apps.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now Python is supported only on the Linux Consumption plan and as of now you cannot edit function using Azure portal for Linux consumption Apps.

I would recommend you to go through this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/88) to understand more

Answer (score 3):

You can use command-line tools to create a Python function app on Azure on consumption or dedicated plans.

Please find the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?tabs=bash%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-python).

Editing functions is not supported at this time for Python function apps on both Consumption and dedicated app service plans. Please check this [GitHub announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/157).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: you can't edit functions using Azure Portal For Linux Consumption Function Apps. You must create a Windows Consumption function app

Comment: But its not allowing me to choose python if I go with windows consumption plan.